# Update Boolean Field in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I got some issues updating a boolean field in MC. 
In fact, I have 2 tables, [Journey - Prospects] and [Contacts]. 
On the Prospects table, I have a boolean field 'Buyer' that is false.

What I want is : 
If the email adress contained in the Prospect table exist in the Contacts table, then I want to update the field 'Buyer' on the Prospects table as 'true'.

Here is my SQL :

```
SELECT

J.[EMAIL],
CASE WHEN (C.[EMAIL] is not null) THEN J.[Buyer] as 'true'
FROM [Journey - Prospects] J

INNER JOIN [Contacts] C ON C.[EMAIL] = J.[EMAIL]
```

But somewhere, my syntaxe is not right, can you help me ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `END` keyword.

Try:

```
SELECT

J.[EMAIL],
CASE WHEN (C.[EMAIL] is not null) THEN J.[Buyer] END as 'true'
FROM [Journey - Prospects] J

INNER JOIN [Contacts] C ON C.[EMAIL] = J.[EMAIL]
```

The syntax of the `CASE` is:

```
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried your way but it still doesn't work.
The syntaxe is now correct and i can run my query, but nothing happen (the FALSE field never become TRUE). I also tried the same thing with a text field (just write False and ask marketing cloud to change it to True). But still doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` syntax is incorrect. See [here for more on SQL CASE statements](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

```
SELECT

J.EMAIL, 
CASE WHEN C.EMAIL IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS BUYER

FROM [Journey - Prospects] J

INNER JOIN [Contacts] C ON C.[EMAIL] = J.[EMAIL]
```